# Nested function not execute on declaration place

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

in android app.

```
  suspend fun getTraidersList(isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false): Any {

            suspend fun execOperation() = traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
            return runOperationWithoutHandle(::execOperation) // real execute here
}

    suspend private fun runOperationWithoutHandle(func: suspend () -> Response<*>): Response<*> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response: Response<*> = func() // in runtime replace by method body (e.g. traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList())
            response
}
```

As you can see in the `getTraidersList` I use nested one line function

```
suspend fun execOperation() = traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
```

The real execute of `traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()` is on line

```
runOperationWithoutHandle(::execOperation)
```

The question is:
Why `traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()`  **not execute** in declaration place?

```
suspend fun execOperation() = traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList()
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: The question is: The nested function is execute only when it call (runOperationWithoutHandle(::execOperation) )? In declaration place (suspend fun execOperation() = traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList())  it not execute. Is I'm right?

Comment: Yes. In your code it's only executed with `func()`.